# how i can increase URLFetch data received size per day

Tags: google-apps-script

is that possible to increase URLFetch data received size per day form external URL data received? my quota limits dashboard shows 0mB / day.

Comment: Recently the limitation of 1 day was removed. Now it's 50 MB/call for each account. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations So I think that now 0 mB/day is displayed at the [dashboard](https://script.google.com/dashboard/quota). If this was not useful for your situation, I'm sorry.

Comment: Welcome. I'm glad your issue was solved.